# Rouche’s Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

How many roots does $z^5-1+iz^2/(10^{10})$ have in the unit disk?

I know I have to apply Roche’s theorem, but I am not so sure if my approach is right.

This is my idea

$g(z)=iz^2/(10^{10})$ and $f(z)=z^5-1$

$|g(z)|=|i/(10^{10})z^2|=1/10^{10}\leq2=|f(z)|$

Hence there are five zeros inside the unit disk.

I want to be sure if the solution is correct.

Comment: $|f(1)| = 0 \neq 2$

Comment: I look at the disc |z|=9/10 instead of the unit disc f(z)=-1 and g(z)=z^5+iz^2/10^10.                             |g(z)|<=|z|^5+1/10^10|z|^2<1=|f(z)|
So, by Rouche’s theorem, there is no zeros inside |z|=9/10 How do I show that there are or there is no zeros inside 9/10<=|z|<=1.

Comment: @user8675309 Can you guide me on how to solve this problem?